# изменить цвет заблокированной кнопки

Tags: css, javafx

Хочу чтобы при наведении на нее изменялся цвет (кнопка заблокирована), делаю так:

```
.button:disabled:hover{
-fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: input[disabled]:hover {
    background: red !important;
}

Comment: @Даниил не работает

Comment: к чему впрос, если все и так правильно реализованно?

Comment: @Air не правильно, это не работает

Comment: а, что за префикс  -fx-? впервые вижу?

Comment: @Air это javafx css. Там используются такие префиксы

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, благодарю, уже прочитал, нашел статью..  )) Но спасибо, приятно не оставаться без внимания...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как не работает?

```css
input[disabled]:hover { 
   background: red !important; 
   -fx-background-color: red;
}

a[disabled]:hover { 
   /* background: red !important; */
   /*-fx-background-color: red;*/
}

button[disabled]:hover{
   background: red !important; 
   -fx-background-color: red;
}
.button[disabled]:hover { 
   background: red !important; 
   -fx-background-color: red;
}

.button:disabled:hover{
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input disabled type="button" value="Кнопка">
<button disabled>Кнопка</button>
<a disabled="disabled" href="#!" class="button">Кнопка</a>
```

Comment: и щас не работает?

Comment: мне нужно для приложения написанного на Javafx

Comment: @Youlfey изменил

Comment: [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600687/hover-and-active-only-when-not-disabled)